# JSONata data mapping template

Tags: json, jsonata

I'm starting to use JSONata for data transformation and I was wondering if there exists a way to have a file which contains values transformation for some fields in json file.

I will have to do multiple transformation types, but most cases will be to translate a field value from "A" to "B" for example and I will be easier to do that in a file in order to not create new versions of data transformation and just will be necessary to create a new entry in this file.

Regards

Comment: Provide an example of what you want to achieve.
You can always store JSONata expression in a file and load it as as string , update it and write it back to same/different file. [In NodeJS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` to perform simple mappings. For example, with the following JSON:

```
{
  "mapping": [
    { "a": "a1" },
    { "b": "b1" }
  ],
  "values": [
    "a", "b"
  ]
}
```

You can map the `values` using:

```
values.$lookup($$.mapping, $)
```

In which case the result will be:

```
[
  "a1",
  "b1"
]
```

Alternatively you can look at `$sift` which will allow you to write a function to sift through the mappings.